# This loop to copy strings into an array overwrites itself and I do not know why

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a function that reads a file, which is a list of names, and then store these names in an array declared as `char **Names;`. Here is a piece of my code:

```
char TempName[15];
Names = malloc((NumOfNames + 1) * sizeof *Names);

x=0;

while(fgets(TempName, sizeof(TempName), fpn))
{
    Names[x] = TempName;
    printf("%s", Names[x]);
    x++;
}

for(x=0; x<NumOfNames; x++)
{
    printf("%s", Names[x]);
}
```

Elsewhere in the program, the number of names in the file is calculated and stored in `NumOfNames`.

In the `while` loop, `Names[x]` prints out each of the names in the file correctly, but in the `for` loop, the last name in the file is printed out `NumOfNames` times. I do not understand why elements `Names[0]` to `Names[NumOfNames]` are all overwritten with the last name read in the file.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: `Names[i]` points to TempName for all i, so of course they are all the same value.  You need to store the data.

Comment: `Names[x] = TempName` - that isn't how you copy strings in C. You're storing the same buffer address (`TempName`) in each slot. Thus the last entity you read will be what is shown for *all* slots. There are *hundreds* of duplicates of this question, but alas the context in which it is asked is so general and the titles so nebulous, its is difficult to quickly locate one (bummer).

Comment: Use `Names[x] = strdup(TempName);` and don't forget to `free(Names[x])` when your are done.